# How to test ApplicationEvent in Spring Integration Flow

Tags: kotlin, spring-integration, spring-webflux

In my Spring project(WebFlux/Kotlin Coroutines/Java 17), I defined a bean like this.

```kotlin
@Bean
fun sftpInboundFlow(): IntegrationFlow {
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from(
                Sftp.inboundAdapter(sftpSessionFactory())
                    .preserveTimestamp(true)
                    .deleteRemoteFiles(true) // delete files after transfer is done successfully
                    .remoteDirectory(sftpProperties.remoteDirectory)
                    .regexFilter(".*\\.csv$")
                    // local settings
                    .localFilenameExpression("#this.toUpperCase() + '.csv'")
                    .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
                    .localDirectory(File("./sftp-inbound"))
            ) { e: SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec ->
                e.id("sftpInboundAdapter")
                    .autoStartup(true)
                    .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000))
            }
            /*            .handle { m: Message<*> ->
                            run {
                                val file = m.payload as File
                                log.debug("payload: ${file}")
                                applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(ReceivedEvent(file))
                            }
                        }*/
            .transform<File, DownloadedEvent> { DownloadedEvent(it) }
            .handle(downloadedEventMessageHandler())
            .get()
}

@Bean
fun downloadedEventMessageHandler(): ApplicationEventPublishingMessageHandler {
        val handler = ApplicationEventPublishingMessageHandler()
        handler.setPublishPayload(true)
        return handler
}
```

And write a test for asserting the application event.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = [SftpIntegrationFlowsTestWithEmbeddedSftpServer.TestConfig::class]
)
@TestPropertySource(
    properties = [
        "sftp.hostname=localhost",
        "sftp.port=2222",
        "sftp.user=user",
        "sftp.privateKey=classpath:META-INF/keys/sftp_rsa",
        "sftp.privateKeyPassphrase=password",
        "sftp.remoteDirectory=${SftpTestUtils.sftpTestDataDir}",
        "logging.level.org.springframework.integration.sftp=TRACE",
        "logging.level.org.springframework.integration.file=TRACE",
        "logging.level.com.jcraft.jsch=TRACE"
    ]
)
@RecordApplicationEvents
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class SftpIntegrationFlowsTestWithEmbeddedSftpServer {
    companion object {
        private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SftpIntegrationFlowsTestWithEmbeddedSftpServer::class.java)
    }

    @Configuration
    @Import(
        value = [
            SftpIntegrationFlows::class,
            IntegrationConfig::class
        ]
    )
    @ImportAutoConfiguration(
        value = [
            IntegrationAutoConfiguration::class
        ]
    )
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(value = [SftpProperties::class])
    class TestConfig {

        @Bean
        fun embeddedSftpServer(sftpProperties: SftpProperties): EmbeddedSftpServer {
            val sftpServer = EmbeddedSftpServer()
            sftpServer.setPort(sftpProperties.port ?: 22)
            //sftpServer.setHomeFolder()
            return sftpServer
        }

        @Bean
        fun remoteFileTemplate(sessionFactory: SessionFactory<LsEntry>) = RemoteFileTemplate(sessionFactory)
    }

    @Autowired
    lateinit var uploadGateway: UploadGateway

    @Autowired
    lateinit var embeddedSftpServer: EmbeddedSftpServer

    @Autowired
    lateinit var template: RemoteFileTemplate<LsEntry>

    @Autowired
    lateinit var applicationEvents: ApplicationEvents

    @BeforeAll
    fun setup() {
        embeddedSftpServer.start()
    }

    @AfterAll
    fun teardown() {
        embeddedSftpServer.stop()
    }

    @Test
    //@Disabled("application events can not be tracked in this integration tests")
    fun `download the processed ach batch files to local directory`() = runTest {
        val testFilename = "foo.csv"
        SftpTestUtils.createTestFiles(template, testFilename)

        eventually(10.seconds) {
            // applicationEvents.stream().forEach{ log.debug("published event:$it")}
            applicationEvents.stream(DownloadedEvent::class.java).count() shouldBe 1
            SftpTestUtils.fileExists(template, testFilename) shouldBe false
            SftpTestUtils.cleanUp(template)
        }
    }
}
```

It can not catch the application events by `ApplicationEvents`.

I tried to replace the `ApplicationEventPublishingMessageHandler` with a constructor autowired `ApplicationEventPublisher`, it also does not work as expected.

Check the complete test source codes: [SftpIntegrationFlowsTestWithEmbeddedSftpServer](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/blob/master/integration-sftp/src/test/kotlin/com/example/demo/SftpIntegrationFlowsTestWithEmbeddedSftpServer.kt)

**Update**: The applicationEvents does not work in an async thread, either applying a `@Async` on the listener method or invoking `applicationEvents` in a async thread, the application event records did not work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that `@RecordApplicationEvents`, so I would register an `@EventListener(File payload)` in the support `@Configuration` with some async barrier to wait form an event from that scheduled task.

You can turn on a DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.integration` and Message History to see in logs how your message travels. If there is one at all according to your SFTP state.

Comment: Have just migrated Spring Integration Event module tests to the `@RecordApplicationEvents`. So, turns out it works only with the main test execution thread. Your use-case is fully async, so it is really doubtful that yours ` eventually(10.seconds)` would pass with this `ApplicationEvents`.

Comment: But Spring Application Event itself should support async. I rarely use `ApplicationEvents` to check the events, but Spring does not support MockBean on applicationEventPublisher, in the past projects, I could use `await()....` to assert the final result in database.

Comment: Verified, even applying an `@Async` annotation on the listener method, the `applicationEvents` does not work.

Comment: Right, so for asynchronous events we cannot rely on this `@RecordApllicationEvents` and register a manual listener with async barrier like a `CountDownLatch`